# oracle 11g rac on Linux virtual box

Tags: oracle11g

We have configured a RAC server having 2 nodes with below details

rac1
public IP [192.168.0.201], Private IP [192.168.2.12] and also a SCAN IP mentioned DNS server [192.168.0.205]

Similarly

rac2
public IP [192.168.0.202], Private IP [192.168.2.13] 
and same SCAN IP mentioned DNS server [192.168.0.205]

After this we have created GRID and installed database on both the nodes using Real Application Cluster Database Installation.

We are able to connect Internally but not from outside. Can anyone please help me to connect it from outside. I mean how End user is going to connect the Database. Can you please help me how listener and tnsnames configuration if there should be any. And how Failover mechanism is going to be work on RAC. Can anyone please explain with Example.

Answer (score 1):

Are you receiving an error when connecting from a client?  What does your TNS entry look like?

Take a look at this site -

http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/OracleDB11gR2RACInstallationOnOEL5UsingVirtualBox.php

I used this as a reference when setting up a RAC environment on Virtual Box.  The only big difference between the article and how you have described your environment is that you have defined the scan-ip address to round-robin in your DNS instead of your /etc/hosts file.

Here are some commands you can run from the command line of either node in the cluster:

```
# Check instance statuses
srvctl status instance -d <dbname> -n <nodename>
srvctl status instance -d <dbname> -n <nodename>

# Check database status across all nodes
srvctl status database -d <dbname>

# Stop service on a single node
srvctl stop instance -d <dbname> -n <nodename>

# Get database config info from OCR
srvctl config database -d <dbname>

# Display current scan configuration
srvctl config scan

# scan_listener info
srvctl config scan_listener
```

I'd start with your tnsnames.ora entry and go from there.